# 14.04LTS not booting, ..timer error

Tags: 14.04, boot, server

I recently got given an old server from a friend, and have been attempting to set it up as a plex media server.

So I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04LTS (Long story short, 16.04LTS and the server GPU don't play nice). Here's the issue: When I power on the server it posts, brings up the Ubuntu selection screen, then, no matter if I choose recovery mode or normal, it freezes mid-boot, on the following error:

```
..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
```

The OS boots in a different (desktop) PC, but for some reason hates the server
I've tried google and /r/techsupport, but no help there. Although I've got a fair bit of experience in desktop computers, servers, terminal OS's and linux in general are fairly new to me.

I can list any other specs I need, but this is what I though would be important.
Help me internet, I need my media streams!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try disabling ACPI on boot by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> in the boot menu (grub2) and add `acpi=off` at the end of the line starting with `linux`.

You're not the only one to experience ACPI hangs...  **;-)**